# Invalid length for a Base64 char array or string when deserializing

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

```
 [System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]
    public ActionResult addItem()
    {
        var tae = Request.Form[0];  
        var ctx = new Models.CangsODEntities4();

        Models.Item item = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Models.Item>(tae);

        ctx.Items.Add(item);
        ctx.SaveChanges();
        Response.StatusCode = 200; 

        return Content(item.itemID.ToString());

    }
```

Here is my POST method. The variable **tae** receives the JSON string with 5 indexes excluding the primary key attribute since I'm adding and the isDeleted attribute since it's auto-generated. [Pls refer to this image to see the JSON string passed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/evZU4.png).

It then goes to **Models.Item item** where I deserialized **tae**. [This is how the JSON object looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRoTX.png).

However, after **Models.Item item** is deserialized, i receive an error message: *Invalid length for a Base64 char array or string*. What could possibly be the solution here? I searched the internet, but I couldn't find any solution for this certain situation.

This is how my angularJS looks like when passing the JSON string:

```
 getBase64(file : File ){
         var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        reader.onload = function () {

            ProductService.imgstring=reader.result.split(',')[1];           
        }.bind(this);
        reader.onerror = function (error) {
            console.log('Error: ', error);

        };


  }

  addItem(data:any,pic:File){
   this.getBase64(pic["0"]);
   setTimeout (() => {
        console.log(ProductService.imgstring);
        data["picture"]=ProductService.imgstring;
        console.log(data);
         let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        let reqopt = new RequestOptions({
            headers: headers
        })
        this._http.post(this._productAddUrl,JSON.stringify(data), reqopt).subscribe(function(res){
            this.response=res;
            alert(this.response);
        });

    }, 5000)
```

**Models.Item** looks like this.

```
 public int itemID { get; set; }
    public string itemName { get; set; }
    public int itemQuantityStored { get; set; }
    public decimal itemPrice { get; set; }
    public int purchaseCount { get; set; }
    public byte[] picture { get; set; }
    public int isDeleted { get; set; }
```

Comment: Which line is the code failing on?

Comment: @SBFrancies When I debugged it, it stops here:  **Models.Item item = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Models.Item>(tae);** giving the error *Invalid length for a Base64 char array or string*

Comment: A Base64 string needs to be a length divisible by 4. If it isn't you need to add enough equals signs to the end so that it is. e.g. "abc" -> "abc="

Comment: @SBFrancies I tried adding "=" but it gives me an error: *'Unexpected character encountered while parsing value =. Path", line 0, position 0.'*

Comment: Did you add the = to the tae json string? That's not the issue - the issue is that the picture byte[] is expecting a valid base64 string and its length isn't correct.

Comment: Converting `json` to a byte[], then converting the byte[] to a Base64 string then converting that back to a byte[] makes no sense at all. Please show us the value of `json`.

Comment: @SBFrancies I used the **.length** method and its length is 102968 which is divisible by 4.

Comment: Is that the length of tae or the length of the picture property of the json string?

Comment: @DourHighArch Please refer to the top since the picture of the JSON object and JSON string is there. Sorry, just disregard the code after **Models.Item item = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Models.Item>(t‌​ae);** since the error is when i try to deserialize it.

Comment: @SBFrancies It is the length of the picture property of the JSON string.

Comment: As a test I suggest you change `byte[] picture` to `string picture` in the model. This should at the very least give a different error and hopefully will allow the deserialisation to work. You can then examine the string in visual studio and try to see what might be wrong.

Comment: @SBFrancies ok I will try this now, does that mean I will also change the data type of my picture attribute from image to byte in ms sql?

Comment: I wouldn't worry about the sql for now.

Comment: @SBFrancies thanks, it actually worked, I have no more error in deserializing, however the error occurs when I try to add it since the data type doesnt match in the database.

Comment: I think this shows that the picture string wasn't a valid base 64 string but I'm not really sure what was wrong with it if the length % 4 = 0;

Comment: @SBFrancies The data types of the picture attribute are conflicting since in the item Model I changed it to string while in the database, its data type still remains as image.

Comment: Yes, you'll have to change the property back to a byte[] and work out what is wrong with the base64 string.

Comment: The image you linked to shows the value of `item`, not of `json`, and does not even include all of the string. Post the actual string value to your question, not a link to a screen shot.